# How to remove javascript resize function for responsive design?

Tags: javascript, responsive-design

I have been created responsive design for my web page.

For my slider function i m using javascript for responsive design.

Here is my code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        initSlider();
      });

      function isMobile() {
        return /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera
     Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
        }

  $( window ).resize(function() {
if (!isMobile()) {
  initSlider();
window.location.href = window.location.href;
}
  });


      function initSlider()
      {
        if ($( window ).width() < 1024 &&  $( window ).width() > 922)
        {


            }); 

      }
        else if ($( window ).width() < 921 &&  $( window ).width() > 771)
        {


            }); 

      }
        else if ($( window ).width() < 770 &&  $( window ).width() > 568)
        {


            }); 

      }
       else if ($( window ).width() < 569 &&  $( window ).width() > 361)
        {

            }); 

      }
        else if ($( window ).width() < 360 &&  $( window ).width() > 331)
        {


            }); 

      }
        else if ($( window ).width() < 330 &&  $( window ).width() > 250)
        {


            }); 

      }
        else
        {

            });

        }
      }
    </script>
```

When i run this code i got responsive design but.. every time it get refresh the page automatically..

So i need to remove the resize function with the same responsive design functionality.

May i know, is there possible to avoid resize function or overcome this refreshing problem(every time) in my web page?

**Note:** I can't to use css for this particular slider responsive design.

Comment: To stop the browser refreshing the page on resize, remove this line of code: `window.location.href = window.location.href;`

Comment: If i remove window.location.href = window.location.href;line means .. i can't  get responsive design sir.. thanks..

Comment: Reloading the page on resize is the exact opposite of responsive. Responsive design demands that the page dynamically responds to changes in the size of the viewport.

Comment: @sdgluck: My responsive design is,, not for normal slider.. it is dynamically change the image when i resize the window.. so for that only i m using javascript.. so i need to avoid refresh the page with this same functionality.. thanks..

Answer (score 0):

U can try customizing this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

if(window.innerWidth<800) {

$(".red").css("background","grey");

}

$(window).resize(function(){

if(window.innerWidth<800) {

$(".red").css("background","grey");
  $("div.dropdown").find("#stores").removeAttr("data-toggle");

} else if(window.innerWidth>800) {

$(".red").css("background","red");

   $("div.dropdown").find("#stores").attr("data-toggle","dropdown");

}

});

});
```

source : https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/jquery-window-resize-fires-only-once/